# Ionic Framework - Updating view from controller

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework for my PhoneGap/Cordova project. I am having some issues in updating the view from the controller.

This is the view I am using.

```
<ion-view view-title="Designs">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>{{items.url}}</p>
        <p>{{items.notes}}</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Below is my controller code. I am getting some data from remote cloud server and it can have 0 or more data at any given point of time. I want these values to be captured and shown in the above view template.

Basically I understand that it needs to be put in an array. I am not sure how that array can be parsed in the view in a loop.

```
app.controller('ViewCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {

    var query = some-remote-data-source();

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    // How to assign the values which can be displayed in the view?
                    $scope.items = results[i].url();
            }

        },
        error: function(e) {

        }
    });
});
```

Kindly let me know if I have missed any data that might help to answer this.

Comment: Is the $scope.items just empty in your frontend? Is the array populated (chrome inspector)?

Comment: Hi, i am looking to know the best way to populate the array in ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favourite: This find() function is communicating with a webservice? Maybe written in PHP? Most of the webservices are returning the data in JSON format. So the only thing you have to do in your controller is:

```
$scope.items = response;
```

So what you need to do is: Edit your webservice so it´s returning JSON formatted data.

If you´re not using a webservice you can populate your array the angular way (do this in your loop):

```
$scope.items.push(items[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop have you try to print in the console **$scope.items**?

```
console.log($scope.items);
```